# How to change the rendered numbers on this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, pygame

The program consists in generating 2 random numbers, rendering them on screen (with the '+' symbol, because it's a sum) and expecting the user to put the result of the sum on the box entry. The code already has a function that generates 2 random numbers (`x` and `y`), and another one that renders them on screen (besides the score). Here is the code:

```py
import pygame
import random
from InputBox import InputBox

pygame.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Projecte MatZanfe")
font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 50)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
user_text = ''
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
running = True
points = 0

def start_the_game():
    x = random.randint(0, 10)
    y = random.randint(0, 10)
    is_correct = False
    return x, y

def display_the_game(x, y):
    # Variables
    z = x + y
    surface.fill((255, 70, 90))
    text = font.render(str(x) + "+" + str(y), True, (255, 255, 255))

    text_surface = base_font.render(user_text, True, (255, 255, 255))
    surface.blit(text, (260, 120))
    input_box.draw(surface)
    punts = font.render("Puntuació: " +  str(points),True, (255,255,255))
    surface.blit(punts, (350,30))

x, y = start_the_game()
input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)

while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        else:
            result = input_box.handle_event(event)
            if result != None:
                if int(result) == int(x) + int(y):
                    # TODO: when the user is right
                    points = points + 5
                    start_the_game()
                    pygame.display.update()
                    display_the_game(x, y)
                    pygame.display.update()
                    
                else:
                    # TODO: when the user is wrong
                    start_the_game
                    pygame.display.update()
                    display_the_game(x, y)
                    pygame.display.update()

    display_the_game(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

I need the program to generate two new random numbers if the result is right and render them, apart from adding 5 points to the "Puntuació" that appears up to the right (done). If the user is wrong, it just needs to generate 2 new random numbers, and render them (the score doesn't have to change).

Here is the code from the imported InputBox.

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 400))
COLOR_INACTIVE = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
COLOR_ACTIVE = pygame.Color('dodgerblue2')
FONT = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 32)
base_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 32)
color_active = pygame.Color('lightskyblue3')
user_text = ''


class InputBox:

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, h, text=''):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.color = COLOR_INACTIVE
        self.text = text
        self.txt_surface = FONT.render(text, True, self.color)
        self.active = False

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # If the user clicked on the input_box rect.
            if self.rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                # Toggle the active variable.
                self.active = not self.active
            else:
                self.active = False
            # Change the current color of the input box.
            self.color = COLOR_ACTIVE if self.active else COLOR_INACTIVE
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if self.active:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    user_input = self.text
                    self.text = ''
                    self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)
                    return user_input
                elif event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    self.text = self.text[:-1]
                else:
                    self.text += event.unicode
                # Re-render the text.
                self.txt_surface = FONT.render(self.text, True, self.color)

    def update(self):
        # Resize the box if the text is too long.
        width = max(200, self.txt_surface.get_width()+10)
        self.rect.w = width

    def draw(self, screen):
        # Blit the text.
        screen.blit(self.txt_surface, (self.rect.x+5, self.rect.y+5))
        # Blit the rect.
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 2)



def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    input_box2 = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)
    input_boxes = [input_box2]
    done = False

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            for box in input_boxes:
                box.handle_event(event)

        for box in input_boxes:
            box.update()

        surface.fill((255, 70, 90))
        for box in input_boxes:
            box.draw(surface)

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to create new values for `x` and `y` and to reset the input box:

```py
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        else:
            result = input_box.handle_event(event)
            if result != None:
                if int(result) == int(x) + int(y):
                    points = points + 5

                # create new random numbers
                x, y = start_the_game()

                # reset input box (just create a new box)
                input_box = InputBox(190, 250, 200, 32)

    display_the_game(x, y)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

[image]